# ¿Cómo interpretar cualquier caracter en una variable en PHP?

Tags: php

Perdonen si esta pregunta ya ha sido respondida con anterioridad pero estoy totalmente perdido con el regex (si es que eso se necesita para solucionar mi problema).

Necesito reemplazar un string con otro, estoy usando el str_replace y me sale perfecto. La función del código es la siguiente:

```
$original = 'abcdef';
$reemplazo = 'correcto';
echo str_replace($original, $reemplazo);
```

El problema surge cuando el string que quiero reemplazar tiene 2 caracteres aleatorios al final del mismo, los cuales pueden ser cualquier letra (a-z, A-Z). ¿Cómo hago para que el código tome en cuenta esas posiciones sin importar que caracter esté?

Me explico:

```
$original = 'abcdef**';
$reemplazo = 'correcto';
echo str_replace($original, $reemplazo);
```

La parte de `abcdef` no cambia, lo que cambia es los siguientes dos, interpretados con los `**` en el código anterior.

Por ejemplo, el string podría ser `abcdefCj`, `abcdefhu`, etc.

Espero haberme explicado y ojalá me puedan ayudar.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar expresiones regulares para eso, por ejemplo:

```
    $cadena = "Esta es una muestra gratisxd de todas las muestras gratisBw que se pueden otorgar";
$r = "disponibles";

preg_match_all("/(gratis)+[a-zA-Z]{0,}/", $cadena, $output_array);

foreach($output_array[0] as $item){
    $cadena = str_replace($item,$r,$cadena);
}
echo $cadena;
```

Allí lo que estamos haciendo es buscar todas las coincidencias de la palabra gratis sin importar que cantidad de caracteres tenga adicionales  y reemplazarla por la palabra **disponible**.

Aqui una [MUESTRA](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/onQ) funcionando

en caso de tener numero y letras serial algo asi:

```
preg_match_all("/(gratis)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}/", $cadena, $output_array);
```

Comment: Perfecto, mi problema se solucionó, de verdad te agradezco mucho. Sólo una última consulta, ¿cómo podré limitar los caracteres adicionales a una cifra exacta? Por ejemplo a 2, como propuse en mi publicación.

Comment: @Gustavo cambia **{0,}** por esto **{2}**

Comment: Muchísimas gracias y felicitaciones, pasé horas buscando esto y no logré solucionarlo; lo hiciste simple y eficaz.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad REGEX se usa para búsquedas/reemplazos más complejos.

Si, como he entendido sólo quieres reemplazar los últimos dos caracteres por otros dos, puedes usar otras funciones más sencillas y menos costosas que REGEX.

### Opción 1: [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php)

Por ejemplo:

```
$original = 'abcdef';
$new='xy';
$result = substr($original, 0, -2) . $new;
echo $result;
```

Lo que le estás diciendo a la función es algo como: *de la cadena `$original`, extrae los últimos dos caracteres `-2` y luego agrega lo que hay en `$new`.*

El resultado será:

```
abcdxy
```

Lo que aquí se crea es una nueva cadena cuyo valor el esperado.

---

### Opción 2: [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr-replace.php)

```
echo substr_replace($original, $new, -2);
```

Te reemplaza los dos últimos caracteres del valor original por el contenido de `$new`.

El resultado sería:

```
abcdxy
```

Aunque esta segunda opción parece más sencilla, es sin embargo más libre y por tanto más propensa a errores.

Como digo en la nota que sigue, conviene establecer un cierto control, y la opción 1 podría resultar más simple si quieres escribir un código controlado que no acepte *lo que sea*, dando a su vez posibles resultados inesperados.

> **NOTA:**
>
> Para este tipo de operaciones conviene siempre crear una función que
> controle los posibles errores. Por ejemplo, que la longitud de la
> cadena no sea menor que el valor positivo de los caracteres que se
> intenta reemplazar, que limpie la cadena de posibles espacios en
> blanco de más, etc.

Comment: Lamentablemente no entendiste mi pregunta, pero me diste datos que me van a ser muy útiles. Te agradezco mucho el tiempo que me dedicaste.